# Hiding datagridview rows from user only when datasource is a bindingsource?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, bindingsource

I had a pre-existing app with a datagridview in it.  For a long time, calls to read or update the dgv were made by looping through rows and pulling cell values.

I decided a few weeks back that, since we ship this data to two foreign systems, it'd be nice to be able to access each row as an object.  So, I created a bindinglist from the data and linked it to the DGV.

One of the problems I've encountered however, deals with hiding some of the rows:  There is a set of radio buttons, "Internal", "External", and "Both" (the default).   Historically, when users would click Internal or External, we'd loop through the dgv and adjust each row's visibility property (based on comparing with a checkbox column that represents the "Internal" option).

For reasons I won't go into, I thought it would be wise for me to remove the row-loop-visibility-change code.  I saw that I could use BindingSource.Filter to filter the row visibility.

However, I'm having one problem, plus I have an additional question.

The problem:  If I click back-and-forth between the three radio buttons repeatedly, it seems like I can't clear the filter properly.  I've tried BindingSource.RemoveFilter() and BindingSource.Filter = null.    I end up with a blank dgv no matter how which of the three options I press.

My question though is:  Does this filtering only affect visibility to humans?  While it's applied, could another thread come in and programmatically update the dgv?  (I'm guessing it could update the datasource, but I'd probably have to make sure to wrap such updates with lock statements and Suspendbinding / Unsuspendbinding.)

Thanks!

Comment: Show your code.  There is no such thing as another thread updating the grid unless you have programmed that yourself.

Comment: I have.  That's been in existence for roughly two years, though I have had to update the code so that we update the datasource instead of the various rows (directly) of the dgv.   But that's not even part of this problem right now, because that happens at 5 minute intervals and I can recreate my visibility / filtering issue immediately after the app loads with data.

Comment: If you want help, post code that reproduces the problem for us.